# Response from WebDriverWait method element_to_be_clickable() in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am building an automation script which will open the browser and login to a portal. It has to click a few buttons and pages. I am using selenium in python, so for example to click a button I am using `WebDriverWait`:

```
BTN= (By.XPATH, '''//a[@ui-sref="app.colleges.dashboard({fid: app.AppState.College.id || Colleges[0].id, layout: app.AppState.College.layout || 'grid' })"]//div[@class='item-inner']''')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(BTN)).click()
```

Is there any return code or any response code I can get from `WebDriverWait` so that in the script I am sure that it runs successfully and I can proceed ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *code trial* is pretty perfect which is as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(BTN)).click()
```

The [**`expected_conditions`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) method [**`element_to_be_clickable()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) returns the *WebElement* when it is *is **visible and enabled*** so you can directly invoke `click()` method on it.

Now as per your comment update if you want to implement *3-4 retry attempts* to click on the element you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

BTN= (By.XPATH, '''//a[@ui-sref="app.colleges.dashboard({fid: app.AppState.College.id || Colleges[0].id, layout: app.AppState.College.layout || 'grid' })"]//div[@class='item-inner']''')
for i in range(3):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(BTN)).click()
        print("Element was clicked")
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timeout waiting for element")

driver.quit()
```